# How to get infos from a movie using mediainfo in a single line?

Tags: text

Mediainfo text is to long for me , so . I'm looking how to configue mediainfo to gives me just those infos : "file name , video codec with bitrate + audio codec with bitrate, size and duration of the movie"
How can I edit mediainfo template ?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 8):

According to the [man mediainfo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man1/mediainfo.1.html) you can use `Inform` option:

```
--Inform=FMT
     Template defined information display.

     FMT is "[xxx;]Text", where xxx can be any one of General, Video,
     Audio, Text, Chapter, Image, or Menu. Text can be the template
     text, or a filename in the form of file:///path
```

---

Here is an example:

```
% mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Codec%" Jellyfish-3-Mbps.mkv
V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
```

Comment: Thank's hg8 for your answer , but can you please simplify your explanation , im noob :'(

Comment: im noob guys , talking me with codes cant help me :(

Comment: @D.Dre that's not code. How are you running `mediainfo`? Just copy the command from hg8's answer directly into your terminal and hit enter. Just change `foo.mkv` to the name of your video file.

Comment: I wanted to get `Frame rate` from the `Video` info but my command `mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Frame rate%" zztop_legs_h264_bp_1080_30_20M.mp4` always gives empty results. How to specify parameters with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Filename, Filesize and Duration are all "General Info-parameters"

Video codec and bitrate are "Video Info-parameters"

Audio codec and bitrate are "Audio Info-parameters"

The following template will get you exactly what you want. (but not in the order specified due to the way the media file is scanned) The colons `:` are not required and are used for readability, the semi-colons `;` ARE required.

```
General;Name=%CompleteName% :Size=%FileSize/String1% :Duration=%Duration/String3%
Video;:%Codec/String% %BitRate/String% 
Audio; %Format% : %BitRate/String%
```

You can use it on your media files by issuing the command:
`mediainfo --Inform=file:///path/to/template/Your1lineminfotemplate.txt test.mp4`

Where  `/path/to/template/Your1lineminfotemplate.txt` is the complete path to your template file and `test.mp4` is the path to your media file.

This results in output similar to this:

> Name=test.mp4 :Size=165 MiB :Duration=00:43:13.690:HEVC :432 Kbps  AAC : 96.0 Kbps

If you need to move these around in a specific order you can always assign specific parts to variables by using `cut` (and in this case the `:` as a delimiter) and then build the output in the order you want by assigning the parts to a new variable for example.

For a complete list of parameters you can query issue the command `mediainfo --Info-Parameters`